# Simple doctrine query not working

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, php-mongodb

My document:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("50935e14253b4a2f18000000"),
   "discussion_id"▼: ObjectId("50831606253b4ac409000002"),
   "author": {
     "userId": NumberInt(1),
     "name": "jini" 
  },
   "text": "50831606253b4ac409000002",
   "createdAt": ISODate("2012-11-02T05: 45: 56.0Z") 
}
```

My PHP code:

```
  //DOES NOT GET ANY RESULTS
$discussionId = "50831606253b4ac409000002";
$dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
$query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('MainClassifiedBundle:Discussion')
->field('discussion_id')->equals($discussionId);
```

BUT THIS GET RESULTS FINE:

```
$discussionId = "50935e14253b4a2f18000000";
$dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
$query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('MainClassifiedBundle:Discussion')
->field('id')->equals($discussionId);
```

I get not results. But when I query against the id, I get results. How come?

Comment: Because discussion_id is a `MongoId` in PHP, wrap it with `new MongoId($discussionId)`

Comment: sorry but can you show an example...sorry.

Comment: `$query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('MainClassifiedBundle:Discussion')
->field('discussion_id')->equals(new MongoId($discussionId));` Like that

Comment: Also I am unsure how this: `$query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('MainClassifiedBundle:Discussion')
->field('id')->equals($discussionId);` can get results, you have no field called `id`

Comment: beats me but it does. Exact same code.

Comment: Doctrine must be decoding `id` as `_id` which in my view is a bad feature, when it gets a field of `id` it transcribes it to `_id` and encapsulates it in MongoId

Comment: yes It seems so . However still does not explain why I have to use MongoId on the discussion_id field as opposed to the _id field

Comment: I guess the driver has done this for you on `id` field, but you have to process the problem yourself with other fields.

Comment: makes sense...I will live with it for now but truly wish Mongo ODM had better documentation.